# How to toggle certain number of div with using css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I got a list of items in react and I want to show some of them and hide the rest upon clicking the button unhide the rest. The issue I am facing is I do not know how to hide an unknown number of div

```
<div class="products-list">
 <div class="item>Item</div>
 <div class="item>Item</div>
 <div class="item>Item</div>
 <div class="item>Item</div>
 <div class="item>Item</div>
 <div class="item>Item</div>
 <div class="item>Item</div>
 <div class="item>Item</div>
 <div class="item>Item</div>
 <div class="item>Item</div>
</div>

.products-list:nth-child(5){
  //how do i target 5th element until to the end (dynamic number of items)
}

document.querySelector(".products-list").addEventListener("click", function(){
 //unhide the ones hidden by css
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are generating the items programmaticly, just add a class from the nth item on you want to hide. Use this class to trigger the action.

Comment: @HansMeiser I have displayed first few with `nth-child` and rest `display: none`but when i click the items set to none don't get style of block expect first one ```. btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.querySelector('.item').style.display = "block"
    })

Answer (score 0):

```js
const items=document.querySelectorAll(".item")

function toggleHide(){
for(const [index, item] of items.entries()){
if(index < 5) continue;
item.classList.toggle("hide")
}
}

toggleHide();


document.querySelector(".products-list").addEventListener("click", toggleHide)
```

```css
.hide {
display:none;
}

.products-list{
background:red;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-list">
 <div class="item">Item</div>
 <div class="item">Item</div>
 <div class="item">Item</div>
 <div class="item">Item</div>
 <div class="item">Item</div>
 <div class="item">Item</div>
 <div class="item">Item</div>
 <div class="item">Item</div>
 <div class="item">Item</div>
 <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

I created a function that iterates over items of node list and toggles hide class for elements with greater index than 4